# Euler Project Problem #17 - Bug in my code

Tags: python

So I am solving the problems from [projecteuler.net](http://projecteuler.net) at the moment and with the 17th problem I got a problem with having a length 100 greater than the actual solution.

The description of the problem is as follows:

> If the numbers 1 to 5 are written out in words: one, two, three, four,
>   five, then there are 3 + 3 + 5 + 4 + 4 = 19 letters used in total.
>
> If all the numbers from 1 to 1000 (one thousand) inclusive were
>   written out in words, how many letters would be used?
>
> **NOTE:** Do not count spaces or hyphens. For example, 342 (three hundred
>   and forty-two) contains 23 letters and 115 (one hundred and fifteen)
>   contains 20 letters. The use of "and" when writing out numbers is in
>   compliance with British usage.

And for my code, I have this one:

```
def problem17(max):
    numbers = {
        0:  0,
        1 : len('one'),
        2 : len('two'),
        3 : len('three'),
        4 : len('four'),
        5 : len('five'),
        6 : len('six'),
        7 : len('seven'),
        8 : len('eight'),
        9 : len('nine'),
        10: len('ten'),
        11: len('eleven'),
        12: len('twelve'),
        13: len('thirteen'),
        14: len('fourteen'),
        15: len('fifteen'),
        16: len('sixteen'),
        17: len('seventeen'),
        18: len('eighteen'),
        19: len('nineteen')
    }

    number_tenths = {
        2: len('twenty'),
        3: len('thirty'),
        4: len('fourty'),
        5: len('fifty'),
        6: len('sixty'),
        7: len('seventy'),
        8: len('eighty'),
        9: len('ninety')
    }

    hundred = len('hundred')
    thousand = len('thousand')
    andl = len('and')

    i = 1
    length = 0
    under_onehundred = lambda i: numbers[i] if i < 20 else number_tenths[math.floor(i / 10)] + numbers[i % 10]
    hundreds = lambda i: numbers[math.floor(i / 100)] + hundred
    while i <= max:
        if i < 100:
            length += under_onehundred(i)
        elif i % 100 == 0 and i % 1000 != 0:
            length += hundreds(i)
        elif i >= 100 and i < 1000:
            length += hundreds(i) + andl + under_onehundred(i % 100)
        elif i % 1000 == 0:
            length += numbers[math.floor(i / 1000)] + thousand

        i += 1

    return length
```

Which will output `21224` instead of the correct answer if I call it with `problem17(1000)`.

Edit: I´m pretty new to python, so I there is anything in general, which I could improve, please let me know in a comment!

**My question is, what is wrong with my code?**

Comment: Have you tried tracing it using a debugger?

Comment: Kind of. I used my old `print-and-die` tactic which I am using in PHP if I dont have access to xdebug. Do you know a good one which I can use in VSCode (no access to PyCharm here at my workplace sadly)?

Comment: IDLE has a debugger, for example, and is probably already installed on your system if Python is.

Comment: for debugging it might be beneficial to have a modified version of your code, that actually prints the numbers as text and only then determines the length.

if you have the number as word you could use following to determine the length.

numlen = len(number_as_word.replace(" ", ""))

Comment: A minor suggestion, which will not solve the issue.

instead of using while and incrementing i you could use

`for i in range(1, max):`

Comment: That´s what I did in the first place @gelonida, but that did not help sadly. Thanks for the tip with the range, I use it often (PHP has it too), but I forgot it probably in the rush to solve it. Do you know, which of both is faster in terms of execution time?

Comment: and when you look at the text output you don't see anything strange?
a few of the 1000 lines must be wrong

Comment: range should be a little faster

Comment: I don´t see anything wrong no when having debug output, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem might be:

```
hundreds = lambda n: numbers[math.floor(i / 100)] + hundred
```

which should be:

```
hundreds = lambda n: numbers[math.floor(n / 100)] + hundred
```

Another problem might be the spelling of 40, which should be "forty" and not "fourty"

Comment: Well spotted, tried it but doesnt change anything :(

Comment: at a second though I'm not sure this fixes it as it seems, that in your context i and n are always identical.

You should still fix it though

Comment: Changed n to i but still same output. Updated my code in OP

Comment: enhanced my answer. Pls check the spelling of 40 (fourty instead of forty)

Reference ( https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/number_spell_words/ )

Comment: OMG. Yes it really was the forty-fourty part. That´s so embarrasing. Thank you so much

Comment: too sad, that source code is not spell checked ;-) You don't want to know how many spelling mistakes you can find in production code even after a product is released.

On the positive side it means, that your  coding logic was perfect

Comment: Yeah ikr, I'm working as a programmer and I have seen everything :D Also English is not my first language, so I have at least an excuse

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is the only problem with your code, but it's a straightforward one: don't use `is` or `is not` on numbers; use `==` or `!=` instead. You may be surprised by the following behaviour:

```py
>>> 1000 + 2000 is 3000
False
>>> 1000 + 2000 == 3000
True
```

Explanation: the `==` operator tests for equality, but `is` tests for object *identity*. In this example, there are two different `int` objects which *equal* 3000, but they are not *the same object*, so `is` gives `False`.

Comment: Oh ok that´s good to know. I changed my if statements accordingly but it still gives me the same output.